# How to enable conversion template argument T to const T?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

Suppose that I have a following class

```
template <typename T>
struct Node { T value; Node* next; };
```

Often one needs to write code similar to this (let's assume that Sometype is std::string for now, although I don't think that it matters).

```
Node<SomeType> node = Node{ someValue, someNodePtr };
...
Node <const SomeType> constNode = node; // compile error
```

One way to work around is to define explicit conversion operator:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node* next;
    operator Node<const T>() const { 
        return Node<const T>{value, reinterpret_cast<Node<const T>* >(next)};
    }
};
```

Is there a better, "proper" way to do it? 
1. In general, what is the proper way to allow conversion of SomeType to SomeType except explicitly defining conversion operator? (Not in my example only).
2. If defining conversion operator is necessary, is reinterpret_cast is the proper way to do it? Or there are "cleaner" ways?

EDIT: Answers and comments were very helpful. I decided to provide more context right now. My problem is not with implementing const_iterator itself (I think that I know how to do it), but how to use same template for iterator and const_iterator. Here is what I mean

```
template <typename T>
struct iterator
{
    iterator(Node<T>* _node) : node{ _node } {}
    T& operator*() { return node->value; } // for iterator only
    const T& operator*() const { return node->value; } // we need both for iterator 
                                                       // for const iterator to be usable

    iterator& operator++() { node = node->next; return *this; }
    iterator operator++(int) { auto result = iterator{ node }; node = node->next; return result; }

    bool operator==(const iterator& other) { return node == other.node; }
    bool operator!=(const iterator& other) { return Node != other.node; }

private:
    Node<T>* node;
};
```

Implementing const_iterator is essentially the same, except that T& operator*() { return node->value; }.

The initial solution is just to write two wrapper classes, one with T& operator*() and the other one without. Or use inheritance, with iterator deriving from const_iterator (which might be a good solution and has an advantage -  we don't need to rewrite comparison operators for iterator and can compare iterator with const_iterator - which most often makes sense - as we check that they both point at same node).

However, I am curious how to write this without inheritance or typing same code twice. Basically, I think that some conditional template generation is needed - to have the method T& operator*() { return node->value; } generated only for iterator and not const_iterator. What is the proper way to do it? If const_iterator treated the Node* as Node*, it almost solves my problem.

Comment: Your reinterpret cast is undefined behavior since it break strict aliasing.

Comment: This might be a use case for `std::variant<Node<T> *, Node<const T> *>`.

Comment: How did it come to this situation? It should not normally occur. `Node<SomeType>` and `Node <const SomeType>` are two unrelated types, they might as well be named `P` and `T`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I had a feeling something is wrong with it. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Why do you need a `Node<const T>` instead of a `const Node<T>`? Do you have a use case in mind?

Comment: @Nelfeal - implementing const_iterator for example.

Comment: @RazielMagius That's not the same situation though. An iterator typically does not own the value of the element it refers to.

Comment: Or if I write a version of smart pointer and I want to allow conversion of SmartPointer<T> to SmartPointer<const T> as T* to const T* is a valid conversion.

Comment: @RazielMagius I'm currently writing an answer right now, but I need you to answer me this: who in your code is responsible for allocating the nodes and who is in charge of deleting them? That will change the outcome of the answer.

Is your node linked list is in charge of deleting itself OR is simply observing other node and another part of your code deletes them?

Comment: @Nelfeal Hmm. Iterator and const_iterator will still be some wrappers around Node*.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot List is responsible for deleting the nodes at the end. reinterpret_cast is needed only for viewing the elements without changing them. Nodes do not delete themself.

Comment: @rustyx I tend to agree. That's the reason compiler forbids it I guess. But there are cases this might be useful - for example implementing const_iterator for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better, "proper" way to do it?

There must be since your solution both has a weird behavior and is also invalid as specified by the C++ standard.

There's a rule called strict aliasing which dictate what kind of pointer type can alias another type. For example, both `char*` and `std::byte*` can alias any type, so this code is valid:

```
struct A {
    // ... whatever
};

int main() {
    A a{};
    std::string b;

    char* aptr = static_cast<void*>(&a);          // roughtly equivalent to reinterpret
    std::byte* bptr = reintepret_cast<std::byte*>(&b); // static cast to void works too
}
```

But, you cannot make any type alias another:

```
double a;
int* b = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a); // NOT ALLOWED, undefined behavior
```

In the C++ type system, each instantiation of a template type are different, unrelated types. So in your example, `Node<int>` is a completely, unrelated, different type than `Node<int const>`.

I also said that your code has a very strange behavior?

Consider this code:

```
struct A {
    int n;
    A(int _n) : n(_n) { std::cout << "construct " << n << std::endl; }
    A(A const&) { std::cout << "copy " << n << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "destruct " << n << std::endl; }
};

Node<A> node1{A{1}};
Node<A> node2{A{2}};
Node<A> node3{A{3}};

node1.next = &node2;
node2.next = &node3;

Node<A const> node_const = node1;
```

This will output the following:

> ```
> construct 1
> construct 2
> construct 3
> copy 1
> destruct 1
> destruct 3
> destruct 2
> destruct 1
> ```

As you can see, you copy only one data, but not the rest of the nodes.

---

What can you do?

In the comments you mentionned that you wanted to implement a const iterator. That can be done without changing your data structures:

```
// inside list's scope
struct list_const_iterator {

    auto operator*() -> T const& {
        return node->value;
    }

    auto operator++() -> node_const_iterator& {
        node = node->next;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    Node const* node;
};
```

Since you contain a pointer to constant node, you cannot mutate the `value` inside of the node. The expression `node->value` yield a `T const&`.

Since the nodes are there only to implement `List`, I will assume they are abstracted away completely and never exposed to the users of the list.

If so, then you never have to convert a node, and operate on pointer to constant inside the implementation of the list and its iterators.

To reuse the same iterator, I would do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct iterator_base {
    using reference = T&;
    using node_pointer = Node<T>*;
};

template<typename T>
struct const_iterator_base {
    using reference = T const&;
    using node_pointer = Node<T> const*;
};

template<typename T, bool is_const>
using select_iterator_base = std::conditional_t<is_const, const_iterator_base<T>, iterator_base<T>>;
```

Then simply make your iterator type parameterized by the boolean:

```
template<bool is_const>
struct list_basic_iterator : select_iterator_base<is_const> {

    auto operator*() -> typename select_iterator_base<is_const>::reference {
        return node->value;
    }

    auto operator++() -> list_basic_iterator& {
        node = node->next;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    typename select_iterator_base<is_const>::node_ptr node;
};

using iterator = list_basic_iterator<false>;
using const_iterator = list_basic_iterator<true>;
```

Comment: I have added some context. My problem is essentially code reuse between iterator and const_iterator, not how to implement them...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want another class altogether, like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct NodeView
{
    T const& value; // Reference or not (if you can make a copy)
    Node<T>* next;

    NodeView(Node<T> const& node) :
    value(node.value), next(node.next) {
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e2312b0580610b6)

If however you are talking about an iterator or a fancy pointer (as you mention in the comments), it's quite easy to do with an additional template parameter and some `std::conditional`:

```
template<typename T, bool C = false>
class Iterator {
public:
    using Pointer = std::conditional_t<C, T const*, T*>;
    using Reference = std::conditional_t<C, T const&, T&>;

    Iterator(Pointer element) :
    element(element) {
    }
    Iterator(Iterator<T, false> const& other) :
    element(other.element) {
    }

    auto operator*() -> Reference {
        return *element;
    }

private:
    Pointer element;

    friend Iterator<T, !C>;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a35e41e57cb97403)

Comment: I think that it should be using Pointer = std::conditional_t<C, const T *, T*> and using Reference = std::conditional_t<C, const T&, T&>. T& const is not a valid type I think.

Comment: @RazielMagius `const T*` and `T const*` are the same. `T* const` is a const pointer. `T& const` is indeed invalid since references are always constant.

Comment: @RazielMagius You are confused. Look at the errors [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd27374a3f60839a). `const` qualifies the thing on its left, unless there is nothing on its left because it's at the beginning of the type, in which case it qualifies the thing on its right.